# Datetime ticks minus ticks results in negative number in the first run

Tags: c#, datetime

I've been trying to develop a function to determine in which day a date falls for a SQL Database to limit the entry to for example only "Saturdays". To solve the problem I decided to do some manual calculations in C# to develop an efficient algorithm, but I encountered something strange by chance.

I decided to subtract the `Ticks` returned by `DateTime.Now` from `Ticks` returned by `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` and I expected a fixed number in a contentious loop but I saw that the first result is surprisingly different while the rest are the same. To examine the problem I tweaked the code a bit to

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

and the following is the output:

[image]

Since the `DateTime.Now` returns a Struct and the same is true for `TimeSpan` and considering the fact that Structs are NOT MUUTABLE, I don't think a mutation might take place but why does it happen? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: You're not reading TimeOfDay in that example, did you mean to?

Comment: It _can_ happen since both expression calculated in same `Tick` or not. You can't expect to return _always_ zero.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: No just an example, why the first number is different since it must be always 0

Comment: @SonerGönül: It has to be always zero or else something very close.

Comment: @Arrrr No. It doesn't has to be. Very close? Yes. But there is no _has to_.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Both technically and logically it has to be, if calculated by hand it must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens, and it will happen by chance is that you're reading the clock twice. Sometimes you will manage to read the clock, then the clock changes, and then you read it again.

The first time this happens there is likely things like JITting that interferes.

You can try this code and see that it will happen a lot:

```
while (true)
{
    var delta = DateTime.Now.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    if (delta != 0)
        Console.WriteLine(delta);
}
```

One second on my machine is 10 million, so 350.000 is about 0.03 seconds.

The reason it turns into a *negative* number is that the sequence is as follows:

1. Read the clock once
2. Read the clock again (this will either be the same value as the first one, or slightly higher)
3. Subtract the second value from the first

Since you're subtracting a value that is either greater than or equal to from a lower or equal value, you will either get 0 or a negative number.

Comment: Is it due to the `long` type which is in Binary and certain numbers cannot be presented in Binary exactly?

Comment: No, time just passes, you look at the clock twice, obviously time has passed in between. The resolution or accuracy of the clock isn't great enough to handle the difference all the time which is why you mostly see zeroes, but when it changes it changes by a few values, like around 10.000, since the accuracy isn't better.

Comment: If what you said is true, The datetime can be very unsafe and we always have to read it twice

Comment: No, why do you think that?

Comment: Because, the first time it returns a VERY different value, if you run it twice very fast, for example in milliseconds interval

Comment: I don't see the problem with that. You're looking at the clock twice, time will have passed, what is the problem with that? It's not like it's time that is going to matter to anyone anyway that small a difference? The very act of reading the current time captures a snapshot of what it was when you executed that code. The next piece of code will already be executing *after* you read the clock, the value is already stale.

Comment: I just understood what you explained. Big Thanks.

Comment: The reason the first time returns a proportionally higher difference than the rest is that since you're running the code for the first time, *more time* passes between the two points where you read the current time, as I said, likely due to JITting of surrounding code. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Lasse, I understood, Thank you, I just read the answer again, I figured that out.